# Laravel Sanctum Middleware on route or controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I´m wondering if there is **any difference** in setting the **auth middleware** directly **on the route** or **in the controller** besides that setting it on the route gives a bit more detailed control if required (e.g. only use it on GET requests)?

**Option 1: Set on the route:**

```
Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class)->middleware('auth:sanctum')->except(['index', 'show']);
```

**Option 2: Set on the controller:**

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Ensure that the user is authenticated to access the resources
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum')->except(['index', 'show']);

        // Ensure that the user is authorized to access the resources.
        // Authorization is handled by the according policy class.
        $this->authorizeResource(Product::class, 'product');
    }
```

What is best practice in your opinion?

Comment: there is functionally no difference, but you actually have more control with the constructor middleware than the one defined on the route resource you have ... the `except` on the route isn't for the middleware, it is for the resource

Comment: Great, thank you... I will stay with the assignment in den controller constructor.